# npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using `ionic 3 whatsapp clone github` project but when i run ionic serve command got this error when i try to install `appscripts` Error `npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.`

Comment: I am also getting this same error. But I have not experienced any issues yet. Can someone give context as to what this is about? Started happening randomly, I assume Browserlist was updated and not this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Uninstal Ionic and Cordova:**

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

**Then clean cache:**

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Then install ionic and cordova again:

```
npm install -g ionic@3.4.0
npm install -g cordova@7.0.1
```

Worked for me!

Comment: @user4350912 Did you try the `npm install` command in the project directory?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using the following command in the project directory:

```
npm install
```

This will install needed packages, so the project can work properly.

#### See also:

- [npm deprecated WARN for newly created app #4926](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4926)

Answer (score 1):

The error itself comes from the package.json file in the browserslist folder in your project.

```
"deprecated": "Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools."
```

I'm installing Laravel but get the same error.

I allowed the `npm install` to go all thr way through and scrolled up. There are some issues present in mine. Will possibly say something like the below.

> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN img-loader@3.0.0 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

You can run `npm install` again if you'd like and this should give you the new errors in a more compact area.

-note: notice the commands below correspond with what is stated after "requires a peer of..."

```
npm i ajv
npm i imagemin@5.0.0
npm install
```

Not sure why, but the imagemin wouldn't work unless I specified the version.

At this point I only had one error left

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

I believe this has to do with me being on a windows machine. If you get this error just force it. If anyone has a better solution at this point I'd love to hear it.

```
npm i -f
```

You could try a reset.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by putting required binaries in the .bin folder under node_modules folder